# Configuring webapp to run upon a ssl certificate on tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, ssl-certificate

How do I configure tomcat 7 to work with a new certificate that I have just bought? I have uncommented the https connector on my server.xml and it looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/home/tomcat7/.keystore" keystorePass="my-pass"/>
```

And my webapp contains a web.xml file configured as:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Viewpoint Secure URLs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

When I try to access it on

```
https://[IP_ADDRESS]:8443/
```

it simply returns that the page could not be loaded. But deploying the same webapp without the transport guarantee my webapp works just fine on the http protocol on 8080.

Another facts that might help:

1. I have bought this certificate to my own domain and I'm tring it on a new server that does not respond to this domain. So I'm trying to access it through the server public IP.
2. I have received the following error after trying a wget from my desktop: "OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure"
3. This is the first time that I have bought a certificate so I may (hope not) have done something wrong anywhere on the process... Like creating the keystore, or the CSR or anything else :/
4. I have NOT done the first import described in this link (https://www.alphassl.com/support/install-root/tomcat.html) because this other link (https://www.alphassl.com/support/install-root-certificate.html) says that I don't need to install the root certificate on my server. Are they, root certificate and  globalsignrootCA.cer, the same thing?

Any ideas?? Should I be able to access my webapp through a signed certificate using my server ip address, or only through the domain connected to my certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: if your configuration is poiting to /home/tomcat7/.keystore then I suppose you have to import your certificate into this keystore

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that I have done it. I guess the problem is that I'm trying to access it through server's ip address not the url...

Comment: glad to know that. Add your own answer and accept it, so you can help others that face a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

First of all verify if tomcat is finding and loading keystore file(verify in catalina.out if there are any errors). However since you have got keystore against your domain name, you cannot access your url with your ipaddress you should access the url with domain for example say `https://abc.com:8443`

Comment: There are no errors on my catalina.out, so I guess the issue is that I'm trying to access it through the server's ip address. The problem is that I'm doing it not to put my real system down. But I guess I have no option...